# Very strange forbidden error on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have been creating links to my website subfolders without the file `index.html` being present (e.G. `example.com/london/en/` expecting it to load the default page within the folder `example.com/london/en/index.html`) however I have been getting a page that simply says `forbidden`.

After various tests I found that the page loaded fine when you entered the URL with index.html at the end. I also found that it worked fine for a different html page. So this led me to believe that the problem lied within that particular html page.

Eventually I narrowed the error down to this line of code:

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"  onload="if(submitted) {window.location='confirmation.html';}"></iframe>
```

I found that when the style tag was removed and moved to the CSS file we have, it loaded perfectly fine. But I have no idea why this solution works! I do not have a lot of experience with programming so perhaps someone here may now?

Comment: Isn't style deprecated? Use CSS.

Comment: The [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute is not deprecated.

Comment: @jyoon - [doesn't look like it](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html#the-style-attribute), and I'm pretty sure `style` contains CSS. Also, that would not cause the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @Sunil - What if you try to remove the `onload` attribute?

Comment: Why do you have `tag` as an attribute?

Comment: @putvande Which tag is an attribute you say?

Comment: @Kobi removed the onload attribute whilst debugging. It wasn't the cause

Comment: @putvande sorry copied the code line over wrong. tag is not supposed to be there. check edit now

Comment: @SunilJindal can we see the context of this iframe?

Comment: weird thing is that the forbidden error does not show when index.html is in the URL. it's only there when I load the folder.

Comment: @jyoon sure. If you follow http://flatser.com/london/test/ you will see the form at the top and an iframe box. I've removed the styling so you can see it

Comment: So removing the style attribute from the html allows you to see the page without the forbidden error but then obviously you see a random iframe on the page that should not be there. Moving this style to the css document completely fixes the issue as I have tested.

Comment: @SunilJindal very strange indeed.

Comment: Can you tell us which web server is this and also which browser you're using?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Hey I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Same issues arise in each. Hosting is on our own server but have moved the files to ecowebhosting and same problem occurs there too

Comment: I haven't asked you about your hosting but about **web server**. Is it IIS, Apache, whatever else?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik it's Apache

Comment: @RobertKoritnik so it's the same error you get if you try to access our images folder http://flatser.com/img/ but I was able to resolve it for flatser.com/london/test by moving the style attribute to a separate css, which I thought to be strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is Windows or Linux?

Forbidden = Permission.

in linux type:

```
chmod 777 index.html
chmod 777 confirmation.html
```

**Update**

Create or update .htaccess file in you www/

```
<Directory /en>
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you don't have permission to browse that folder. Try specifying a file inside that folder.

Comment: But it works when I move style="display:none;" to a separate css file